# on function jquery return false

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter

I am working on a forum. I want to validate form on client side but I am confused ho to validate before submit form.

I used on function but when it returns false I want to show something to the user.

Here is my view:

```
<?php
if($this->session->userdata('email')){
echo form_open('forum/reply');//session form start here
?>
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left media-middle pull-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/pics') ?>/<?php echo $this->session->userdata('profile_pic') ?>" alt="<?php echo $row->first_name . nbs(2) . $row->last_name ?>">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <textarea name="message"  class="text_reply"></textarea>
 <?php 
 $submit = array(
    'name' => 'reply' ,
    'value' => 'reply' ,
    'id' => 'reply' ,
    'class'=> 'btn btn-primary' 

     );
    echo form_hidden('id',$id);
    echo form_submit($submit);
    echo form_close ();?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php }//session form ends here
 ?>
```

Javascript code:

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
    var reply = $ ('.text_reply').val(); 
    if(reply != ''){

    }else{
        return false;
    }


});
```

My controller:

```
public function reply(){


    $this->form_validation->set_rules('reply', 'Answer', 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->topic();
    }
    else
    {
        $data['topic_id'] = $this->input->post('id');
        $data['reply_text'] = $this->input->post('message',TRUE);
        $data['user_id'] = $this->session->userdata('u_id');
        $data['reply_date'] = date('M/d/y');
        $query = $this->mod_forum->reply($data);
        if ($query) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('t_id', $this->input->post('id'));

            redirect('forum/topic');
        } else {
            echo 'something woring please contact admin.';
        }


    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would make sure you prevent the form from submitting like this

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
...
```

Then you need to move your return false to the if block since you are checking there if it is empty

```
if(reply == ''){
    alert('empty');
    return false; 
}else{
    alert('not empty');
}
```

Also notice in the if statement I added another = sign, one = is the way to set values, == is the way you compare two values

Here is a codepen so you can see it working

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNYqJK

Comment: Sorry just noticed your code has != in it, but it still works the same, just make sure you have what you want to do if it's empty in the right place. The important part is making sure you prevent the form form submitting until it's valid.

Comment: when writing on textarea and submit the form its not woking on first click i dont know why but i when i click second time form submited